Paris CDG visiting another terminal airside
I am flying out of terminal 2d. My lounge pass only allows admittance to the lounge in 2e.  Is it possible to access 2e from 2d security?

Do you have the lounge name? Are you transitting? Where are you going?

Which lounge is that? 2E only has AF lounges (4 of them). But security is on a per-terminal basis (per-concourse, really), and I don’t think they would let you enter a terminal without a matching boarding pass. It also takes a little while to get between 2D and any of the 2E concourses. Finally, are you in a Schengen or non-Schengen flight? 2E is only ex-Schengen.

Thank you for this.

I suppose you have a Priority Pass, and would like to use the lounge at the Yotel Air in Terminal 2E gates L.
The page for that lounge on the Priority pass site tells us:

Airside - Non-Schengen departing and transit passengers only. Take the Shuttle train to Gate L. Follow signs for Instant Paris/YOTEL. Passengers travelling from Gates K and M can access the lounge via the Shuttle train but must allow time to return to the gates.

Which implies, but does not make clear, that you can actually get there only from gates K, L and M (the 3 concourses of 2E). It does make clear that only passengers travelling to non-Schengen destinations can use it (or arriving from such destinations).
The hotel's site itself is more explicit:

Our hotel is located airside at Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport in the transit area of terminal 2E (Gate L). To reach us from the public land-side area of the airport, you MUST have a valid boarding pass for Terminal 2E gates K, L or M. These gates are only for international flights outside the Schengen area (EU except from the United Kingdom). You may also reach us if you land in Terminal 2E, stay in the transit area do not clear customs and do not have luggage to claim and re-check.

(emphasis mine)
There is actually a bus (Blue Shuttle) going from 2B/2D to 2F/2E L gates. In 2B/2D, it departs from the non-Schengen area (B gates), and it gets to the eastern end of 2F. From there you have a looooong walkway that gets you to L gates. However:

If you are not departing to a non-Schengen destination I don't think they will let you go through passport control (and if they do they may be annoyed when they have to let you back in).
There may be checks for your boarding pass at some points which may prevent you from getting to a terminal you don't have a boarding pass for.
The whole trip will take quite some time from 2B to L (up to 8 minutes waiting time, 8 minutes trip, and probably 10 minutes walk), and even more on the return trip as the bus continues its loop to K gates, 2A/2C... and Terminal 1: nearly 30 minutes just for the bus trip), so unless you have 4 hours or more in front of you, it probably does not make sense to even try.
There may be security checks somewhere along the way. I don't think there are any, but I'm far from certain.
Getting to the bus from departures should be possible, but as it's not quite a common usage, it may be difficult to find.

Note that the Yotel Air lounge seems quite limited in what it offers, so I'm not sure you're missing much anyway. Note that while Priority Pass says refreshments are available, the Yotel Air site says "Food and drinks are available for a small cost" (seems to be just a few vending machines). It is also limited to 3 hours max. No idea what the exact situation is regarding showers.

Very clear answer. Thank you for your time on this. Guess I'll just have to rough it out!
